# Access to model field in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, view, django-class-based-views, detailview

I have blog and I am able to comment my post. But in the view I have to check if author of comment is the same as logged user.

For Blog model - this is simple - I need only `self.get_object()`
But there is a problem for CommentForm in detail view.

How can I get `author` field of comment model in `BlogDetailView`?

```
class BlogDetailView(generic.DetailView, FormMixin):
    template_name = 'blog_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'blog_detail'
    model = Blog
    form_class = CommentForm
```

Edit:

My models (comments about database design are welocome):

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = RichTextUploadingField()

class Comment(models.Model)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    text = RichTextUploadingField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: Please provide your models detail. We can't guess how have you modeled it.

Comment: @Cheche sorry, please check now.

Comment: If `blog = self.get_object()`, have you tried doing `for comment in blog.comments.all(): print(comment.author)`